# upgrading to Rails 6, and sqlite3 1.4, can no longer query booleans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am upgrading everything, such as Rails 6, and in the process upgraded sqlite3 from 1.3.6 to 1.4

Every query using a boolean attribute no longer works.
For example `User.where(approved: true)` now returns `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` even though there are several users with `approved: true`.

This is my gem file.

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
end
group :production do
    gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I have read that sqlite uses 0/1 instead of false/true, but in my dev database, it's stored as true/false, so even if I rewrote to `User.where(approved: 1)`, it still returns nothing.

This worked fine before the updates. What is the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: While you're in the process of upgrading, you should dump sqlite in dev and move to pg.

Comment: @jvillian That's the conclusion I've come to as well :(  so annoying...

Comment: I believe that using the same DB in development and production is one of those "pretty good practices". It'll be worth your time in the long(er) run.

Comment: Totally agree... I'm just lazy.

Comment: For coders, laziness is a virtue...